# Email not sent when submitting form

Tags: php, forms

I have a very strange issue with a website that I have created.

Basically, I have a site built with a "Poor Man's Router" so that when I go to site.com/contact, it finds index.php in that directory which has a few variables set and an include which grabs my site's skeleton (main structure). Inside the skeleton is where I have another include that grabs the content for the specific page, which is designated by the variable which is set in the index.php file that I had previously mentioned.

So the problem is that when I go to this contact page, I have an contact form on it which is supposed to send an email once it is submitted. Everything appears fine, but the PHP that is on the contact page's content file is never executed. So I seemed to have narrowed it down to an issue where if the content file is deeper than the directory of the skeleton file, it will not work. Let me show you how the directories are:

```
/
--skeleton.php

--/content
----contact.php

--/contact
----index.php
```

So it goes index.php -> skeleton.php -> contact.php

The PHP in contact.php is not working, unless I put it in the root directory. Why does it do this? I know that what I am doing is not the most ideal way, but that's not what I am asking for help with. I just need to know why the PHP is not being executed when the files are organized this way.

```
//INDEX.PHP

$content = 'contact.php';

include('../skeleton.php');
```

```
//SKELETON.PHP

include($site . 'content/' . $content);
```

```
//CONTACT.PHP

if($send_info == 1) {
    // send email
} else {
    // show form
}
```

Comment: Past a code please, code is the best explanation. There's a reason people don't program in english :)

Comment: I added code, but the code is not the problem. It's that a file is including another file, which is including yet another file, but its code is not running which I have narrowed down the issue to where the file is. It works in the root, but not when it's inside the content directory.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code, one suggestion would be that your include files are referencing incorrect paths. Do you know that the skeleton.php and contact.php files are loading? Can you put some debugging lines in each file to echo an output message to show that the files are loading and where they get to? Can you change the include('filename') to require('filename') to see if they are actually getting included?